# Como resolver paradigma de Migraciones en EntityFrameworkCore?

Tags: entity-framework-core, migration

tengo una base de datos que está en un servidor SQL remoto,del cual me conecto para crear una nueva aplicación de ASP.NetCore; ya realicé el primer scaffold-dbcontext para generar mi modelo en NetCore 2.1, sin embargo debido a que algunas tablas no tenían las llaves foraneas y llaves primarias necesarias para EntityFrameworkCore, tube que ejecutar los cambios directo en el servidor.Pero el problema real viene al tratar de agregar dichos cambios al modelo de mi proyecto en mi maquina.Cuando inteto generar un controlador manda el siguiente mensaje
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Concretamente lo que requiero es modificar el modelo ya creado con scaffold para que tome esos cambios y poder utilizar Controlador con acciones de escritura de EFCore

Comment: Segun menciona el error, tienes una relacion de padre/hija pero no lo estas especificando como tal en los atributos de las clases.

Comment: Entonces es necesario poner manualmente atributos [ForeignKey("Codigo")] ?

Comment: Claro. Si quieres mantener la relacion y que EF lo carge si. Ahora bien, tambien puedes utilizar el attributo NotMapped para que EF lo ignore.

Comment: Perfecto, y en mi caso como agregué un campo posterior al scaffolding, tengo q eliminar cualquier modelo relacionado y volverlas a agregar. Gracias @Einer